# C# syntax for "This button is interactable"?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, unity-ui

What should be the C# syntax for the condition **if (This Button is interactable)**?
I have a script attached to the button, Which has to run only if the button is interactable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Downvote: this is something you can probably find within minutes of research, I personally try everything I can before posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have reference to a `Button`, you can use [`Button.interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) to determine if the button is interactable. `interactable` is a member of [the `UI.Selectable` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.html); [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) inherits from `Selectable`, and thus, has access to `interactable`.

The below script takes a `Button` reference, and runs logic if the button is selectable. When you intend to "run the script", simply call `Run()`. The logic will not run, if the `Button` is not interactable.

```
public Button button;

public void Awake()
{
    if(button == null)
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}

public void Run()
{
    if(button != null && button.interactable)
    {
        // run your logic, here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking `button.interactable` checks only if the button itself is interactable, completely ignoring the possible existence of Canvas Groups.

The correct check should use `IsInteractable()` instead of `interactable`:

```
public Button button;

public void Awake()
{
    if(button == null)
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}

public void Run()
{
    if (button != null && button.IsInteractable())
    {
        // run your logic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems wrong. Your first part of the condition does not make much sense. And while `IsInteractable()` is a nicer way to access the bool, it still seems to go as well to check against `interactable`

Comment: [According to the code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uGUI/blob/2019.1/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Selectable.cs#L477), it also checks `m_GroupsAllowInteraction`

Comment: @Zibelas it is not a nicer way of acessing the bool. That is the point. This function and the property test for totally different things (which is omitted in Unity documentation). The bool tests if this selectable's flag is set to true while the method checks if the selectable overall is interactable (taking into account parents that may have Canvas Group with disabled interaction).

Comment: But than that should be explained in your answer why it should check for a canvas group (and not just as a comment)

Comment: @Zibelas It does say in his question _"Checking button.interactable checks only if the button itself is interactable, completely ignoring the possible existance of Canvas Groups. The correct check should use IsInteractable() instead of interactable"_